# SSH access behind router without port forwarding

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to SSH between two computers behind router without port forwarding at least on one end, which is the computer I'm trying to access.
Now. seems like this got something to do with SSH tunneling and I've been trying to achieve something but unfortunately I'm not getting there.

My main purpose is to make a website that will have full access to my computer that's behind the router and be able to control that computer from the website.

Now question is: is this even possible?  I tried to use AWS since I get a public IP that will help me with the port forwarding issue on the computer behind the router but no luck too.

I would appreciate some help or suggestions on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is possible.

Take a look in [Guacamole](http://guac-dev.org).

Guacamole is a clientless remote desktop gateway. It supports standard protocols like VNC and RDP.